# Clients lose permission to Windows 2003 AD

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, permissions

My network has about 20 Windows XP clients. It often happens that a client can't access the shared folders in the Windows 2003 Server that I have; that happens right after logging in. It gives me a "you don't have permission for that resource" error, even though the client has been authenticated by the server. I can fix that in the client by disabling and enabling the network connection. Once I do that, I can access the AD normally.

My network setup is fairly simple: I have a pfsense box that runs dns and dhcp and I the win 2003 server takes care essentially of the AD and shared resources (files and printers).

Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Your clients shouldn't be using the pfsense box for DNS, they should be using the Domain Controller. All kinds of weird things happen when you have non-AD DNS servers configured on domain clients.

I bet that this isn't the only strangeness that you're seeing, but I'll also bet that it's resolved when you point your AD clients to *only* the AD DNS servers.

---

Edit: It sounds to me like when you log in to these machines, you're actually logging using cached credentials, since your DNS setup would make it difficult for your clients to find the DC(s). This would mean that you didn't get your access tokens, so you really wouldn't have permission to the file server, since your account wouldn't have a valid token.

First thing is first, **fix your DNS problem**. Yes, it's a *problem*. After that, you should be verifying that when you log in to the problematic machines that there's nothing actually wrong with your connectivity. Check the server logs, check the client logs, etc.

There's not a whole lot else to say, since you haven't provided a lot of detail other than `It doesn't work`, so check these basic things. If that doesn't work, update your question with more meaningful detail.

Comment: I had the AD as the DNS server before and the problem already existed. This thing has been haunting me for a while now.

Comment: Even if that's the case, you can't even begin to troubleshoot until you have all of the domain clients using **only** AD DNS servers.

Comment: This answer cannot be upvoted enough, pointing Windows clients in an AD environment to anything other than a Windows DNS server is asking for trouble.

Comment: Alright then. I will get pfSense's dhcp to tell the clients to use the AD DNS. I will just up vote the question for now. If that solves the problem, I will mark this as solved.